# Ruby on Rails, How to set a group of attributes unique for another class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

sorry for the unintelligible title but I didn't know how to explain the problem :D
My project consists in building a rail transport site, so I have to write some routes, stops, trains and so on..
I want to know how I can click on the route and see just its own stops.
Now I can see only all stops in general.
I know I'm very confusing, but I hope you can help..thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two models `Route` and `Stop`, you need to define associations between these classes to solve your problem

```
class Route < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :stops
end

class Stop < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :route
end
```

So `stops` table will have a `route_id` column, to fetch all the stops that belong to a route, you can do this

```
route = Route.where(id: params[:route_id]).first
stops = route.stops
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you RSB, I' ve already written the first part, but in which file should I put the second one? Further more, for example..if I click on route 1, it should be linked to "localhost3000/stops"..in other words the stops of each router are in the same page?